# Android - listview with actions

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I was creating my very first app where, I would like to create actions in listview.

I have created listview, but when I click that particular icon from view it should land to a new page where I can indent a web view

```
public class HomeFragment extends ListFragment {

// Array of strings storing country names
String[] title = new String[] {
        "About Us",
        "Attend class",
        "Events",
        "What's hot",
        "Social Networks"


};    

// Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable/
int[] img = new int[]{
        R.drawable.about,
        R.drawable.clas,
        R.drawable.cale,
        R.drawable.hot1,
        R.drawable.socil,

};

// Array of strings to store currencies
String[] description = new String[]{
    "Our Story",
    "vlrn.in",
    "Update Your Schedule",
    "Need a Hot cake ? ",
    "Connect with us",

};


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

    // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
    List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();        

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hm.put("txt", "" + title[i]);
        hm.put("cur","" + description[i]);
        hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(img[i]) );            
        aList.add(hm);        
    }

    // Keys used in Hashmap
    String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" };

    // Ids of views in listview_layout
    int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt,R.id.cur};        

    // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
    // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.fragment_home, from, to);       

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);     
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `onListItemClick` in your `ListFragment`, there you can access the clicked item data and show it on a new page.

```
public void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // do it here
}
```